# Javascript: Unable to get Promises.all responses together

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, redux, response

I'm using a React-Redux action to get some promises responses at once. The fact is I need to link these responses in one combined response.
I have a function that parse the JSONs responses.

For instance:

```
Promise.all([
      fetch('some_backend_resource'),
      fetch('another_backend_resource')])
.then(([response1, response2]) => {
   parseJSON(response1).then(resp1 => {
     // here I dispatch to another function the value of resp1
   });
   parseJSON(response2).then(resp2 => {
     // here I dispatch to another function the value of resp2         
   });
})
```

Then I pass the resp1 and resp2 values to their respective reducers and back in the view component I try to put them together but sometimes it doesn't work because the resp1 prop gets the ComponentDidmount before the resp2 prop.
How can I combine them into a single response and then pass it to the view component?

Comment: Why is `parseJSON()` async?  It doesn't seem like it should be and that is making your problem more difficult.

Comment: @jfriend00 probably because `fetch` response object has an async `json` method to parse the response...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear.  If you want to parse both responses before dispatching, then the *easiest* way is to chain the parsing to the fetch and use `Promise.all` on the result:

```
Promise.all([
  fetch('some_backend_resource').then(r => parseJSON(r)),
  fetch('another_backend_resource').then(r => parseJSON(r))])
.then(([resp1, resp2]) => {
   // dispatch resp1 & resp2
});
```